# please someone explain what exactly last line is doing

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT A.siebel_row_id AS ASSET_ROW_ID,A.SIEBEL_STATUS ,B.STATUS AS THINDB_STATUS
FROM OR_ASSET_THINDB A ,THINDBUSER.MSI B
WHERE A.msisdn=B.msisdn`enter code here`
and b.circle='Orissa'
and DECODE(a.siebel_status,'Suspended','Active','Active','Active','Inactive','Inactive')<>b.STATUS;
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Have a look at the [DECODE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/DECODE.html#GUID-39341D91-3442-4730-BD34-D3CF5D4701CE) function and try to rewrite it using a [CASE expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/CASE-Expressions.html#GUID-CA29B333-572B-4E1D-BA64-851FABDBAE96). This will make things clearer. For you and others who read that code.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about this queries requirement but here is my understanding

**DECODE(siebel_status,'Suspended','Active','Active','Active','Inactive','Inactive')**
  this will function like following:

```
case  
when siebel_status = 'Suspended' THEN 'Active'  
when siebel_status = 'Active' THEN 'Active'  
when siebel_status = 'Inactive' THEN 'Inactive'
end;
```

the result returned from the above would be compared to:
**b.STATUS;**

so the final answer could be like this:
**if('Active','Active','Inactive')<>b.STATUS**

Answer (score 1):

```
and DECODE(a.siebel_status, 
           'Suspended', 'Active',
           'Active'   ,'Active' ,
           'Inactive' ,'Inactive'
          ) <> b.STATUS;
```

It says:

- if siebel_status is *suspended*, pretend it is *active*
- if siebel_status is *active*, well - it is *active* anyway
- if siebel_status is *inactive*, then it remains *inactive*

Then compare it to b.status value.